# Save variable to stack (X86-64 assembly)

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, calling-convention

I've written a small program in x86-64 assembly (AT&T) syntax, and it assembles just fine, but I don't get the result I expected.
I have a variable in register `%rdi`, which I need to modify in a subroutine, and I need to keep the original value for some other usage later. What I want to do is to `push` the original value onto the stack, and then retrieve it again when the subroutine finishes, for example, if the variable is located in `%rdi`.

```
    pushq %rdi
    call subroutine
    movq (%rsp), %rdi
```

Now, I'm not really sure if this is the correct way to do it? I've read somewhere that a subroutine pushes the return value onto of the stack, but does that mean that I have to include an offset when I try to retrieve the variable?

Also I know I have to keep the stack pointer aligned by 16 bytes, which I'm not quite sure if I do. In case I don't, will the assembler then give me an error, or could that be the reason why my program fails?

And by the way, this program is part of an assignment, so I cannot share the code with you, but I hope my description is good enough.

Comment: Cannot imagine what is so secret about your assignment that you cannot share the code.

Comment: It's not secret in any way, but if post the entire program on a website and ask somebody else to correct all the mistakes, then i'm on the verge of cheating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code fragment is suspicious in that it fails to keep the stack pointer balanced across a call sequence, which is probably not the intended behaviour. Typically you would either match `push` and `pop` operations, `push` many times and then `addq $k, %rsp` (where `k` is the combined size of every previous `push`), or keep the frame size constant across the execution of the function and use explicit accesses.

Given that you need to keep keep the stack pointer 16-byte aligned, keeping a constant-sized frame is probably the most straightforward method. It might look like

```
# in the function prologue
subq $K, %rsp
...
mov %rdi, SLOT(%rsp)
call subroutine
mov SLOT(%rsp), %rdi
...
# in the epilogue
addq $K, %rsp
```

Where `K` is enough space for all the local stack state plus enough space for the largest set of outgoing arguments, rounded up to 16, and `SLOT` is a spot on the stack reserved for the value of `%rdi`.

The return value of an integer type usually placed in `rax`, not on the stack. Other types are returned differently (such as by a hidden pointer) - check the calling convention of the compiler you are interfacing with.

Comment: Alright, so according to what i can understand from your answer, the following code will do it?
        subq $16, %rsp
        movq %rdi, 8(%rsp)
        call subroutine
        movq 8(%rsp), %rdi
        addq $16, %rsp

Comment: That looks ok to me, although you would usually have one `subq/addq` pair for the entire function rather than one for each subroutine call.

Comment: Alright thank you so much. My program still dosen't quite behave as expected, but the result has changed. I probably just need to spend some more time looking through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `movq (%rsp),%rdi`, use `popq %rdi` . The first doesn't update the `RSP` stack pointer, so you could be in a problem when returning to the function that called you.

This, of course, if `subroutine` doesn't adjust the stack for itself. It `subroutine` is using the `standard (Pascal) calling convention`, parameters will be removed by the function itself, and not the caller, and you will loose access to the saved `%rdi` value.